# WCF Soap Message Remove 'To' Header

Tags: .net, soap, wcf-security, wcf-client

Although there are other questions on this subject, none really cover this exact problem. I rarely ask questions because I can usually find the answer.

We are using a WCF client to talk to a Java web service that uses Soap 1.1. I had to create a custom WseHttpBinding to add a userNameToken. The problem is that when the request is serialized, a bunch of header elements are added that the Java service hates. These are specifically:

Action
MessageID
ReplyTo
To

The actual header looks like this:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <s:Header>
 <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1"/>
 <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</a:MessageID>
 <a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo>
 <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://xxx.xxx.xxx</a:To>

 <MORE SECURITY ELEMENTS...>
 </s:Header>
```

After researching my options, I couldn't find a way to remove those without writing a custom encoder or manipulating the message before it was sent. I chose the latter.

Using a custom behavior, I used the IClientMessageInspector to implement a messageInspector class. In the BeforeSendRequest method, I used the following:

```
message.Headers.RemoveAll("Action", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
message.Headers.RemoveAll("MessageID","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
message.Headers.RemoveAll("ReplyTo", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
message.Headers.RemoveAll("To", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
```

I was quite surprised that it removed all of the headers exception for one. Here is the result:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://pilot.eidverifier.com/uru/soap/ut/usv3</a:To>
<MORE SECURITY ELEMENTS...>
</s:Header>
```

As you can see, the 'To' element is still there. So, my question is why? Does it require that to send the message?

I can't help but feel that I'm approaching this the wrong way. Is there a way to make mustUnderstand false? Is there a property setting that removes all of the extra elements? I'm in release mode.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: I should add that the initial error coming back from the Java service is : MustUnderstand headers: [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing}To, {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing}Action] are not understood.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `messageVersion`,

to remove, Use `Soap11` instead of `Soap11WSAddressing10`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem in WCF Core using

```
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

resolved by switching to

```
MessageVersion msgver = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(msgver, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```